# Facebook Audience Network Framework SDK 5.3.2 Error

Tags: ios, xcode, ads

Xcode : 10.2.1

Language : swift

FB SDK Version : 5.3.2

Hello guys can you help me to solve this problem with new facebook audience network framework SDK 5.3.2??
When i integrated this framework it returns 57 error logs.
I had tried many times to search this problem on google but can't able to find any proper solutions.

Old Facebook Framework Works Properly.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can add the framework of the screenshot below. When I updated the Facebook SDK before, the new version used some new APIs and needed new framework dependencies.

[image]

And add the VideoToolbox.framework and CoreMotion.framework.

Comment: Thanx for helping it will work Good.  But now it gives 4 Error. I have update my question.

Comment: @sohil add the VideoToolbox.framework and CoreMotion.framework

Answer (score 1):

Facebook Audience Network Framework SDK 5.4.0

Add Framework Screenshot below : [image]